# understanding event attachment code in Pure JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey guys i am new to JS and basically know a litte about Jquery , so i was going through [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/from-jquery-to-javascript-a-reference--net-23703)(Jquery in plain Javascript) article and they have the following example :

```
 $('a').on('click', fn);
```

In this example, we're attaching a click event listener to all anchor tags on the page.

The above Jquery code is rewritten as follows :

```
[].forEach.call( document.querySelectorAll('a'), function(el) {
   el.addEventListener('click', function() {
     // anchor was clicked
  }, false);
});
```

now i understand how call() works in JS and also how forEach works in JS , but i don't understand what the `[]` is doing right in front of the `forEach` , its very difficult to understand the order of execution in the above code , also who is passing `el` inside the `function(el)` ?

can somebody explain ?

Thank you.

Alex-z.

Comment: declaring array of elements. Then looping through it with forEach?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `[]` is a shortcut for `Array.prototype`, so it's really

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call( document.querySelectorAll('a'), callback );
```

It takes the native `Array.prototype.forEach` and calls it with the resulting nodeList from `querySelectorAll` as it's first argument, the `this` value, and the callback as the second argument.

Calling it like that lets us pass in non-arrays, like objects that are "array-like", in that they have a length property, such as `arguments` or a nodeList, objects that otherwise couldn't be iterated by using `Array.forEach` directly on the object.

Comment: you mean calling a it like this `[].prototype.forEach.call` allows to iterate over non-arrays vs calling like `Array.prototype.forEach.call` ??

Comment: No, I mean they are both exactly the same, `[]` is shorthand for `Array.prototype`, and calling that with `call` in this way makes it possible to iterate over array-like objects, that can't be iterated by doing for instance `document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function() ...` because a nodeList is not an array.

Comment: is [] being populated with the results of document.querySelectorAll('a') before function(el) runs ??

Comment: `[]` is an array, an empty one. All arrays have a `forEach` method, as that method is prototyped on the constructor. All arrays are also instances of the native `Array` constructor, so `Array.prototype.forEach` and `[].forEach` is the same function, but when chained to an actual array that array is set as the `this` value, but in this case that doesn't matter as `forEach` isn't called with parentheses, it's called with `call()` which sets it's own `this` value from the first argument passed to it, so it's the same thing

Comment: And no, the array is not populated, it's just an empty array used to get access to `Array.forEach` without writing `Array.prototype.forEach`